# Vuejs dynamically disable dropdown option

Tags: vuejs2

I have two select boxes, for the second the values can be disabled depending on the first

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <select v-model="hoursDayB" @change='disableOptions()'>
                                                 
                        <option v-for='dataB in hours' :value='dataB.id'>{{ dataB.name }}</option>
                      </select>
                      <select v-model="hoursDayE">
                                                   
                        <option v-for='dataE in hours' :disabled="dataE.id < hoursDayB" :value='dataE.id'>{{ dataE.name }}</option>
                      </select>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
     hours:[], 
     hoursDayB: 0,
     hoursDayE: 0,
  },
methods: {
            getHoursDays: function(){
            this.hours = JSON.parse('[{"id":"0","name":"00:00","disabled":1},{"id":"1","name":"01:00","disabled":1},{"id":"2","name":"02:00","disabled":1},{"id":"3","name":"03:00","disabled":1},{"id":"4","name":"04:00","disabled":1},{"id":"5","name":"05:00","disabled":1},{"id":"6","name":"06:00","disabled":1},{"id":"7","name":"07:00","disabled":1},{"id":"8","name":"08:00","disabled":1},{"id":"9","name":"09:00","disabled":1},{"id":"10","name":"10:00","disabled":0},{"id":"11","name":"11:00","disabled":0},{"id":"12","name":"12:00","disabled":0},{"id":"13","name":"13:00","disabled":0},{"id":"14","name":"14:00","disabled":0},{"id":"15","name":"15:00","disabled":0},{"id":"16","name":"16:00","disabled":0},{"id":"17","name":"17:00","disabled":0},{"id":"18","name":"18:00","disabled":0},{"id":"19","name":"19:00","disabled":0},{"id":"20","name":"20:00","disabled":0},{"id":"21","name":"21:00","disabled":0},{"id":"22","name":"22:00","disabled":0},{"id":"23","name":"23:00","disabled":0}]');
            },
            disableOptions: function(){

            },
        },
        created: function(){
            this.getHoursDays();
        }
})
```

The problem that the values is disabled randomly
https://jsfiddle.net/hams123/1w6u8q4h/1/

Comment: parse the time into a date then compare, horrid example:https://jsfiddle.net/7mtsgvLr/

Comment: Thanks  Lawrence, why i have to do that ?
Why not testing with id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison was in string, so we must cast to integer

```
<div id="app"> 
     <select v-model="hoursDayB" @change='disableOptions()'>                                   
         <option v-for='dataB in hours' :value='dataB.id'>{{ dataB.name }}</option>
     </select>
     <select v-model="hoursDayE">                                     
         <option v-for='dataE in hours' :disabled="(parseInt(dataE.id)) < (parseInt(hoursDayB))" :value='dataE.id'>{{ dataE.name }}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hams123/1w6u8q4h/7/